# Perl script to connect to Sybase database

Tags: perl, sybase

I am writing a Perl script to connect to Sybase machine having particular  database name called PPDB but it is not working.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:Sybase:server=sybase IP address; database=PP_DB;port=5000","sa", "password" );
```

This is the error I'm getting

> Can't connect to data source 'dbi:Sybase ASE:server=server
>   name;database=PP_DB;port=5000' because I can't work out what driver to
>   use (it doesn't seem to contain a 'dbi:driver:' prefix and the
>   DBI_DRIVER env var is not set) at ./update_database.pl line 6

Don't know what's wrong in this. Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Define "not working". What makes you believe this? What have you done to debug it? What is the return value of the call to connect? What does $DBI::errstr say?

Comment: Can't connect to data source 'dbi:Sybase ASE:server=server name;database=PP_DB;port=5000' because I can't work out what driver to use (it doesn't seem to contain a 'dbi:driver:' prefix and the DBI_DRIVER env var is not set) at ./update_database.pl line 6                                                This is the error getting

Comment: Have you installed [DBD::Sybase](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Sybase) from CPAN?

Comment: Yes I have DBD:Sybase installed from CPAN

Answer (score 2):

The `server` parameter in the data source name expects a Sybase server *name*. If you want to specify an IP address then you need to use `host` instead:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Sybase:host=<sybase IP address>;database=PP_DB;port=5000', qw/ sa password /);
```